# CSS Justify-Content: Flex-End Not Working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a GitHub homepage clone with HTML and CSS before I move on to JS. I'm currently on the navigation bar and I'm having some trouble with the bell icon, plus sign icon, and profile image icon on the right. However, it's stuck in the center. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
#nav-bar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 53px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#profile-nav-bar {
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

#profile-nav-bar li {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul id="profile-nav-bar">
            <li>
                <i class="far fa-bell"></i>            
            </li>
            <li>
                +
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="far fa-user"></i>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align-items` property for `#nav-bar` is what I removed, then specified positioning along the two flexbox axes for the `#profile-nav-bar` container. [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```css
#nav-bar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 53px;
    display: flex;
}

#profile-nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

#profile-nav-bar li {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
          <ul id="profile-nav-bar">
              <li>
                  <i class="far fa-bell"></i>            
              </li>
              <li>
                +
              </li>
              <li>
                  <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <i class="far fa-user"></i>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- Font awesome -->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e03d7ac5cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, and it worked! However, I played around with your solution, and it turns out that as long as I added `width: 100%` before `#profile-nav-bar` it would work. Thanks for the help! I spent so much time on this lol.

Comment: @JoshuaLiu No problem. Feel free to upvote my answer if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

#nav-bar { **align-items: center;**} this could be why its stuck in the center

I believe it should be the UL that is justified Flex-end

```
 <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul id="profile-nav-bar">
        <li>
            <i class="far fa-bell"></i>            
        </li>
        <li>
            +
        </li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="far fa-user"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```